# Prove that two lines are parallel

Tags: geometry

There are two circles and two common tangents. A, B, C and D are the points where the tangents touch the circles. How can I prove that AB is parallel to CD?
[image]

Comment: Hint. Think about the perpendicular bisector of $AB$.

Comment: It comes through the center of the circle.

Comment: Not a proof, but in geometry that diagram can be interpreted as a "homothetic transformation". They have the property that every line is parallel to its homothetic image. Homothetic transformations are the direct application of Thales theorem. The point where the lines AD and BC intersect is the center O of the transformation . If you can show that the small and big circle are homothetic (with respect to O) then the same happens for A and D, and B and C, so AB and CD are homothetic and thus parallel

Comment: I don't understand why the perpendicular bisector of AB comes through the center of DC.

Comment: It happens for every chord of every circle. If a chord has endpoints A and B, the triangle ABO (where O is the center of the circle) is isosceles (OA=OB=radius of the circle). The height of that triangle at O is then the same as the perpendicular bisector of AB

Comment: No, wait, I mean it comes through the center of another circle, not through the center of the same circle.

Comment: @student28 Good question: why would the perpendicular bisector of $\;AB\;$ **also be** the perp. bisector of $\;CD\;$ and, thus, pass through the center of $\;d\;$ ? Again, this follows from the fact that this perp. bisector, extended to the left, will pass through the intersection point of the two lines $\;f,\,g\;$ .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: circles with chords and tangents][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f5KAc.jpg)Extend $DA$ and $CB$ to meet at $E$. Find centers $F$,$G$ and join $FA$, $FB$, $GC$, $GD$. Then since $\triangle ABF$ is isosceles, $\angle FAB = \angle FBA$. Subtracting these from right angles $FAE$ and $FBE$ gives $\angle EAB = \angle EBA$. Therefore $$\angle EAB = \frac{(\pi- \angle AEB)}{2}$$ By the same argument, $$\angle EDC = \frac{(\pi-\angle DEC)}{2}$$ And since $\angle AEB = \angle DEC$, therefore $\angle EAB = \angle EDC$ and $AB$ is parallel to $CD$.

Answer (score 0):

An idea: let $\;O\;$ be the intersection of the lines $\;f,g\;$ (if they don't intersect then they're parallel and the claim follows at once. Cna you see why?). Then observe that we get

$$|OA|=|OB|\;,\;\;|OC|=|OD|\implies \frac{|OA|}{|OD|}=\frac{|OB|}{|OC|}$$

and the claim follows from the [Converse of Thales Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intercept_theorem)